# Django REST Framework: Exclude a specific route while retain standard ViewSets

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-rest-viewsets

I am using Django REST Framework (DRF) for my API. In particular, I have set up several routes using the `ModelViewSet`, without much additional coding. In particular, I have a route like

`/api/v1/collection/<key>`

From all the possible keys, I do need to block one specific key, say `special`. Any request with any HTTP verb to `/api/v1/collection/special` should result in a HTTP 404 error.

I can think of two approaches:

- Override some method on the `ViewSet` hierarchy. Which one?
- In `urls.py`, set up a higher-precedence URL route that intercepts this URL, like `path("collection/special", view=<404View>, name="collection-exception")`. Does this make sense? What would be the appropriate exception view to route to?

What is the recommended approach? Any of the above, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `ModelViewSet` then you should overwrite the `get_queryset()` method. If key value is wrong then raise the Exception otherwise return the queryset:

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound 

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        key = self.kwargs.get("key")
        if key == "special":
            raise NotFound()
        return MyModel.objecs.filter(pk=key)
```

Comment: Does this also work for `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` requests?

Comment: I think HEAD and OPTIONS are not used to get the response. They have different purposes. The 404 should be returned for GET.

Comment: Ah, I see that my question was imprecise. I would like to "hide" the resource with the `special` key. Hence, all HTTP verbs should fail.

Comment: Try to add a URL that will raise an exception or show an error view when called